# Next.js: How can I create subdirectories for a static site?

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js, jamstack

I'm using React/NextJS to create an application which will eventually be served as a static site. I have predefined urls I need to create in subdirectories. For example, `/technology/` should go to `/technology/index.html`

How do I create this in the Nextjs `pages` structure?

I've tried various combinations of the following, with no luck:

- Adding `trailingSlash` to my nextjs config:

```
module.exports.trailingSlash = true;
```

- Adding `technology.js` to my pages directory (also tried `/technology/index.js`)
- Adding `exportPathMap` to my next.config.js:

```
exportPathMap: async function (
    defaultPathMap,
    { dev, dir, outDir, distDir, buildId }
  ) {
    return {
      '/': { page: '/' },
      '/technology/index.html': { page: '/technology' },
    };
  },
  trailingSlash: true
```

Comment: Those should work. What issue are you having exactly?